# Can't install VS2013 Ultimate or uninstall VS2012

Tags: visual-studio

I've been trying to install Visual Studio 2013 for HOURS and I have no idea what to do. Every time I launch the setup I get:
"Setup detected an issue during the operation. Please click below to check for a solution and help us to improve the setup experience".

After that it tells me to check my CBS.log file, and I understand none of the contents, but here it is: http://pastebin.com/zQdfHW7n

I am running Win8.1 preview.

I've tried the following:
 - Running it as admin
 - Running it in comp. mode (WinXP, Vista, Win7, Win8)
 - Uninstalling VS2012 (but getting the exact same error)

Someone please help! :(

Comment: You've tagged your question with `vs-2013-preview` and say *I am running Win8.1 preview.* All this software has GA versions, so use that instead.

Comment: Sorry, that tag was a mistake. I trying to install vs2013, not vs2013 preview.

Comment: Rollback to previous restore point.

Comment: Check your event viewer. Any error messages showing up in there?

Comment: VS2013 RTM is incompatible with 8.1 Preview.  And since 8.1 RTM is a free upgrade, @ta.speot.is's comment is still the most valid.